# What's the importance of Turmeric in Indian Marriage and Husband in context?

Tags: belief, rituals, tradition, marriage, superstitions

It is said that when a wife applies Turmeric to her feet then the husband is influenced to be on the rightful path (dharma maarg). Most of my elders, grand parents and ancestors have been talking about the same...

Is there a Vedic proof or something?

Is it a customary thing that has been performed on each of the festivals and been followed to date just like that (with no scriptural recommendation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following informations are obtained from the book called [Dharma Bindu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf)(which is the essence or Sara of all Dharma Shastras) regarding the importance of Turmeric(Haridra/Haldi) in a married Hindu woman's life:

Vyasa Maharshi gave the instructions as follows:

> ***Haridraam***kumkumamchaiva sindhuram kajjalam tathaa, Kurpaanakam cha taambolam mangalaabharanam shubham/ Kesha samskaara kabari kara
>   karnaad bhushanam, Bhartur aayushyami -cchanti dooshayenna Pativrataa/
>   Praatah kaaletu yaa naari dadyaadarghyam vivasvate, Sapta janmaani
>   vaidhavyaam saa naari naiva pashyati
>
> **Those women who are interested in the longevity of their husbands
>   should not to ignore the high significance of turmeric powder**,
>   kumkuma, eyetex, vastra, jewellery like ear studs, bangles, necklaces
>   etc. As at the early mornings, women offering Arghya or water for
>   worshipping Surya Deva would aviod widow hood for seven births ahead!

[image]

So,the importance of Turmeric(in a married HIndu lady's life) is indeed mentioned in Hindu scriptures.

Comment: Turmeric is a disinfectant. It protects women working in the household from germs and minor poisons, is beneficial for her and family, husband included.

Comment: Thats only a rational explanation based on ayurveda.Where rationality ends starts spirituality.